# RPi @ Raspbian: docker image build returned a non-zero code: 134 on .net restore command

Tags: docker, build, raspberry-pi, .net-6.0

I switched recently from .netcore 5.0 to .netcore 6.0 on my Rasberry Pi (ARM CPU).

I am trying to build a docker images, that does successfuly build with .net 5.0 on RPi 4B+ @ ARM , (and even now builds with both .net 5.0 and 6.0 -> on intel/amd CPU wsl/ubuntu),

However, now with .net 6.0 on RPi/ARM I get (for 2 different images) the following error:

> Step 12/28 : RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"  --->
> Running in 9060829a297a Aborted (core dumped) The command **'/bin/sh -c
> dotnet restore** "/MyProject/MyProject.csproj"' **returned a non-zero
> code: 134**

From my investigation, I could not figure out what exactly that means, I just got a strong guess that it must be linked to the new build environent (.net 6.0)

[Here](https://komodor.com/learn/exit-codes-in-containers-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/) and [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-docker-container-exit-codes-5ee79a1d58f6) are listed some container exit codes, but that did not give me much wisdom, leave alone, I'd need image build exit codes rather :)

I tried:

- docker pruning all dangling images
- deleted/re-downloaded all microsoft .net core images  as prepositions to docker build with .net 5.0 or 6.0

If it is an issue of .net6.0 for ARM, I did not find this reported on github, or elsewhere.

Thank you for any hints..

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649399/how-to-run-amd64-docker-container-on-arm64-host

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to something in the libseccomp2 package. It should be fixes if you update to the latest version

```
apt-get install libseccomp2/buster-backports
```

Comment: Thank you @studiobram - I'll try on my next attempt to upgrade.
I had to downgrade for more reasons for now..