# how to run amd64 docker container on arm64 host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, x86-64, ubuntu-18.04, arm64

I have Ubuntu server installed on a dedicated server

> root@instance-20220616-1428:~# uname -a
> Linux instance-20220616-1428 5.4.0-1071-oracle #77~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 25 13:42:26 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I'm trying to run a container on docker but the architecture of my container is based on AMD64 whenever my server has a system based on AARCH64 (ARM64 ).

This is my configuration file to run my container :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  xui:
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: xui
    image: 'theraw/xtreamui-on-docker:xtream-ui-beta2'
    shm_size: '1GB'
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:25462:25462'
      - '0.0.0.0:25461:25461'
      - '0.0.0.0:25463:25463'
      - '0.0.0.0:25464:25464'
      - '0.0.0.0:25465:25465'
      - '0.0.0.0:25500:25500'
      - '0.0.0.0:3306:3306'
    ulimits:
     nproc: 65535
    cap_add:
     - ALL
    command: []
```

This is how I run my container :

```
root@instance-20220616-1428:~# docker-compose -f xui.yml up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container xui  Started                                                                                                                                                                                     0.7s
root@instance-20220616-1428:~#
```

but when I checked the status of the container this is what I got :

```
root@instance-20220616-1428:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
5abce281fadd   theraw/xtreamui-on-docker:xtream-ui-beta2   "supervisord --nodae…"   11 minutes ago   Exited (1) 11 minutes ago             xui
root@instance-20220616-1428:~#
```

I have already implemented the platform and everything looks great but I don't know why always the status of my container is Exited.

Please help.

Comment: Can you run your app (uncontainerized) ?
What happens when you run:
_docker run --privileged --user=root --name=xtream_test_run  theraw/xtreamui-on-docker:xtream-ui-beta2_
Does it fail ? Can you read logs and guess the crash reason from them ?